# Error while using JDL application options: got value 'elasticsearch' for 'search'

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I'm testing out jHipster's JDL application options, but I can't get it to work, I think I followed the documentation on https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#application_options for the specific error I'm getting:

> Error: The option's name and value must be valid to create an option,
>   got value 'elasticsearch' for 'search'. Error while parsing
>   applications and entities from the JDL Error: The option's name and
>   value must be valid to create an option, got value 'elasticsearch' for
>   'search'.

Here is the JDL relevant section

```
   application {
  config {

    packageName es.fasam
    baseName fasam
    applicationType monolith
    authenticationType jwt 
    cacheProvider ehcache 
    buildTool maven
    clientFramework angularX
    enableHibernateCache true
    enableTranslation true
    languages [es,en]
    nativeLanguage es
    prodDatabaseType mysql
    searchEngine elasticsearch
    serverPort 8085
    skipUserManagement false
  }

}

@service(serviceClass)
@paginate(pagination)
@search(elasticsearch)
entity Actividad {
    nombre String,
    fechaDeInicio ZonedDateTime,
    fechaDeFin ZonedDateTime,
    ubicacion String
}


.
  .
  .
  .
  entity B {...}
  entity C {...}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug with annotations. You can specify the entity options using the old fashion until it is fixed. https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#-annotations

Comment: It worked. I got it working by removing the `@search` annotation and added it at the end `search A, B, C  with elasticsearch`. Should I report this bug?

Comment: I opened an issue yesterday here: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/issues/360